# Apache redirect full URL with RewriteRule

Tags: apache-httpd, mod-rewrite

I have a redirect problem with 'RewriteRule', i have this in mt .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/foo/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

If i go to foo.domain.com redirect to www.domain.com/foo/ and it's ok, instead i go to foo.domain.com/bar i have an error, must go to www.domain.com/foo/bar.
Where is error?

Comment: Are you trying to run the site from ./foo folder?

Comment: Can you do something like use Firefox's "Live HTTP Headers" add-on, and watch the redirection take place? With HTTP, just looking at a log file sometimes doesn't give you the whole picture.

Comment: With "Live HHTP Headers" the next redirect after foo.domain.com/bar is www.domain.com/fooindex.php

Answer (score 0):

Apache (or mod_rewrite) might be constructing the "Location:" header line wrong. Add a slash to the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo.domain.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/foo/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

When I tried this without the slash, I would get "Location:" header lines that looked something like: `http://www.stratigery.com/foo//whatever`. I'm not sure that all browsers can handle an extra slash in the URL.

Comment: Not work, with `/` redirect to www.domain.com

Comment: Nothing? Any ideas?

Comment: @hellb0y77 - turn on mod_rewrite logging and see what happens. The directive is: `RewriteLogLevel 3`, and you probably want to specify the log file with: `RewriteLog /var/tmp/rewrite.log` or some directive like that. The log file output isn't terrifically natural, but you might be able to puzzle it out.